# Reverse bit problem right shifting code doesn't work in one condition while work in other

Tags: c++, while-loop, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I was solving a question related to bit reversing 32 bits and found out that my code was not working due to some interchange of code lines, although the logic seems no problem.

This is the code which gives wrong answer:

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t x=0;
    int c=32;
    while(c--){
        if(n&1) x=x+1;
        x=x<<1;
        n=n>>1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

However, if I position the line `x=x<<1` right before the `if` condition, it surprisingly works:

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t x=0;
    int c=32;
    while(c--){
        x=x<<1;
        if(n&1) x=x+1;
        n=n>>1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Please help me to understand the logic behind this problem.

Comment: The first implementation is wrong. Take a pen and trace the code writing each step in a paper. This is the best learning approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider an artificial example when a number of the type `uint32_t` contains only one bit. So you can have either 0 or 1.

And this statement

```
    if(n&1) x=x+1;
```

sets the only bit. For example it sets x equal to 1.

But after that the number is shifted

```
    x=x<<1;
```

and you lost the set bit.

In the second code snippet the shifting operation is performed if there is a guarantee that the number has a bit that has not been checked yet. And the first shifting operation when x is equal to 0 in fact does not have an effect.